# Why don't Democrat or Republican partisans register and vote in swing states?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, voting

Since swing states are often the deciding factor in US presidential elections, why don't Democrat or Republican partisans register and vote in swing states? Or perhaps they are already doing so and it's already part of the US election traditions?

Looking at https://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/voter-id.aspx#Details ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201107211924/https://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/voter-id.aspx)), it seems one can simply use one's passport when voting, and looking at one example of vote registration form (I took New Jersey as an example), one is supposed to have only stay in the state [30 days](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/voter-registration.shtml) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201107213049/https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/voter-registration.shtml))  before the registration and I'm not even sure whether it is really checked since it seems [SSN is enough to register](https://voter.svrs.nj.gov/register?ref=voteusa) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201107212150/https://voter.svrs.nj.gov/register?ref=voteusa)). Staying somewhere a few weeks (or perhaps less) in a swing state to vote there sounds like something some Democrat or Republican partisans could do. Or did I miss something?

Comment: What do you mean?  Every state has partisans on both sides, and they will be voting in their home states.

Comment: @JoeC I mean: don't vote in your typical home state but instead stay a few weeks (or perhaps less) in a swing state to vote there.

Comment: Not every state requires people to register with a party. Texas, for example, does not do so. The only constraint is that one can vote in at most one primary election in one election cycle. Other states are similar. Even in states that do require registration to vote in a party's primary, they typically do not require party registration to vote in a general election.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks, I didn't mean party registration, but simply [vote registration](https://voter.svrs.nj.gov/register?ref=voteusa),  if needs be.

Comment: A similar schema of moving voters was [intended in the 1850s in Kansas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Ruffian) although not for a presidential election.

Comment: Not quite duplicate: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/54256/what-prevents-dc-residents-from-registering-and-voting-elsewhere/

Comment: In the UK there was an open campaign for students and people to live on boats to register temporarily in a voting district where their vote matters.

Comment: Keep in mind that "swing states" swing because they have roughly equal numbers of partisans already. If there were a practical way to compel thousands of people to upend their lives to go vote in another state just to sway the election, the parties would be doing it, likely in roughly equal numbers. That would cause those swing states...to remain swing states.

Comment: 30 days may be a reasonable vacation for ordinary folk in some places, but here in the states, spending 30 days somewhere would be a crushing economic hardship for most.  Also, 99% of people here only care enough about politics [to shoot their neighbors over](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/anti-donald-trump-campaigner-clayton-carter-shoot-republican-dead-head-george-jennings-a7895966.html), but not enough to drive several hours into another state.

Comment: @MarsRobertson I am not sure of the rules overall, but generally, students in the US vote where they're from, not where they're living for school, since they return home each summer. If they settle down and *don't* go home, they can legit vote where their school is. Perhaps the rules are different in the UK to enable that scheme.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- "since they return home each summer." - that's the whole point! And ruling party knows it. That's why students were complaining the date of the election was 12th December - after the semester ended. People who live on boats were also encouraged to move temporarily. Fully legally, totally officially. System. Game. Play the game.

Comment: @MarsRobertson Works for me. Lots of people encourage students to register to vote in their new town, especially if it's a red state. They don't always, though. I even oppose having restrictions on how long before an election you have to be resident; but here we are.

Comment: I just saw a news article on this subject: "A Florida attorney is at the center of a new state investigation after elections officials say he recently attempted to register to vote in Georgia and instructed other Florida Republicans on how to do it... registering to vote with no attempt to stay in Georgia can be punishable by a felony charge that can carry up to a ten-year sentence, and $100,000 fine." https://www.wsbtv.com/news/politics/florida-attorney-under-investigation-registering-vote-georgia-encouraging-others-do-same/L6LTC2AHBFDMXPOTZKVMO5ESJQ/

Answer (score 70):

Simply put, because it is a crime. It is not allowed (e.g. in [Minnesota](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/201.014)) to move somewhere for a month to vote there. Plus, most people can't afford such a disruption to their life.

When I registered to vote in Minnesota, I got a letter from my old state asking to confirm I'm no longer resident there (and reminded me if I had indeed moved, it was illegal to vote in my old state). So states do talk to each other, and would probably notice if I re-registered multiple times within a few months.

Yes, you could probably get away with it in some states. But to swing a state, you would have to convince thousands of people to commit a crime in order to most likely not affect the outcome. You could not openly organize thousands of people to move somewhere temporarily in order to swing a state because, again, it's a crime.

Finally, if you do move just to vote, that means you don't get to vote locally. In many cases, giving up your right to vote in the actual town/county/district you *actually* live in is not worth faking living somewhere for a month to commit a crime.

There was a website put up after the 2016 election that helped you find the closest swing district to  you, so you could maybe move and flip a House rep, but I can't find that tool any more.

Comment: You can only vote in the state of your primary residence. This is also why politicains vote in their home states and not as part of Washington DC, despite owning second residences there and staying in DC for large chunks of the year. Besides, it is very much worth voting in the state of your primary residence, since the local elections will have much more of a direct impact on you. Even if you manage to vote in a swing state, you suddenly cannot vote for your governer, state congress, town council/mayor/commissioners and ballot measures such as tax/funding measures. It's not worth it.

Comment: Also bear in mind that changing your residence impacts on things like taxes, if you take up residence in a new state you would be expected to file and pay taxes there. It would be a LOT of work for one single vote.

Comment: I don't think the question was asking if you can vote in multiple states, but if you could move to a more important one for a few weeks if your old state was guaranteed to vote for a certain candidate.

Comment: Yes, that is the question I answered.

Comment: That link makes it look like it is legal to move to Minnesota 20 days before registering or voting.

Comment: @Jetpack Yes, if you legitimately move to Minnesota 20 days before an election, you are eligible to vote. The important part is "maintain residence," which you are not doing if you return to a previous residence after voting.

Comment: That law says that in order to be eligible to vote, you must "maintain residence in Minnesota for 20 days immediately **preceding** the election." That doesn't prohibit moving out of Minnesota *after* the election.

Comment: @TannerSwett MN statues don't define "maintain residence," as far as I can tell. But other sources indicated "maintain residence" means a genuine attempt to live somewhere. If you rent in SD, and then rent a place in MN, and then go back to the same address in SD, then you did *not* maintain a residence in MN, you did in SD, and you can only maintain one residence at a time. But yes, if you genuinely picked everything up, signed a one-month lease in MN, and then left and signed a new lease in WI, then you would have been eligible to vote in MN.

Comment: But the reason why people don't do this is because nobody wants to legitimately move somewhere to swing *one* vote. Moving is expensive and stressful. As another answer points out, the grand you can easily spend on moving would be far more effective as a donation to a candidate or PAC.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, good point. I wouldn't be surprised if a judge interprets it your way.

Answer (score 22):

The stakes have to be higher than just a presidential election.  This DID happen in U.S., prior to the Civil War, in Bleeding Kansas (from Wikipedia):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeding_Kansas

> Missouri, a slave state since 1821, was populated by many settlers
> with Southern sympathies and pro-slavery views, some of whom tried to
> influence the decision by entering Kansas and claiming to be
> residents. The conflict was fought politically as well as between
> civilians, where it eventually degenerated into brutal gang violence
> and paramilitary guerrilla warfare. The term "Bleeding Kansas" was
> popularized by Horace Greeley's New York Tribune

but Nebraska and Kansas were swing stages for control of the balance of slave states and free states in congress.

Comment: Good answer. The practice is also more impactful when the population is small, as a relatively small number of people can have a very large effect. In an 1854 election, just a couple of thousand of individuals fraudulently voting in Kansas were enough to outnumber the legal votes by 2:1 - this would require many, many more people to pull off nowadays.

Answer (score 11):

Around [$11 billion](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/10/01/election-2020-campaign-spending-set-to-hit-record-11-billion.html) was spent on presidential campaigns. While that sounds like a lot, that works out to less than $100 per voters. It would cost most people more than $100 to move to a battleground state. Their money would be more efficiently spent by giving it to the candidate of their choice, or to a political action committee (PAC) supporting them.

Comment: If they spend $100 on advertising per voter, that doesn't mean they can buy an extra vote for $100 - probably not even for $5,000. Most voters have already made up their mind to the extent that no amount of paid advertising will swing them.

Comment: I don't think this casual relationship actually works like you're making it out to be. Let's assume, to make things easy, that Biden spent 5.5 billion and Trump spent 5.5 billion. Are you saying that if Trump instead spent 11 billion, he'd be able to get twice the votes? How would that actually happen?

Comment: @user3153372 Interesting to compare $100 with the *maximum legal spend* by each candidate per voter in the UK, which is less than $1. Maybe the US should spend a few $bn improving the electoral process (e.g. speed of vote counting) instead of wasting it on media advertising! (In the 2017 UK general election, the total spend of 75 political parties and 18 independent campaign groups was less than £50m.)

Comment: The ironic thing is that advertising is generally considered a prisoner's dilemma: if both parties spend more, they're generally worse off than if they both spent less. Perhaps the people who'd be happiest with such limits are the parties!

Comment: @user3153372 I think you misunderstand the purpose of such advertising. It is designed and intended to sway **no one**. What it *is* designed and intended to do is to inspire you to hate the other side with such intensity (or remind you that you already do) that you will *definitely* turn up to vote no matter how lukewarm you are about the compromise candidate your party ran.

Comment: @alephzero speed of vote counting has almost never been an issue before the current elections with a huge number of mail-in ballots. Elections unless extremely close are usually decided within a day or two.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, a problem which could be solved by abolishing the two-party system. After all, you can't make a voter hate 7 out of 8 parties in one ad, without hurting your own party as well.

Comment: @qwr It's *still* not an issue. Just inconvenient.

Answer (score 8):

In the 1980s [the Rajneeshee cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajneesh_movement) attempted this on a much smaller scale in [Wasco County, Oregon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasco_County,_Oregon). That's the classic cultists in orange robes while their aloof leadership drives around in Rolls-Royces. They weren't partisan in your sense, but they illustrate how it can be done, and how it can be stopped.

[image]

Rajneesh and thousands of his followers moved to Wasco County with a population of just 22,000. They incorporated themselves into the city of [Rajneeshpuram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajneeshpuram), zip code 97741. Further expansion of Rajneeshpuram was mired in legal conflict with claims that it was essentially property of a religious organization and its incorporation violated separation of church and state, as well as investigations into immigration violations.

They looked to the nearby tiny town of [Antelope, Oregon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antelope,_Oregon#Demographics) (population then about 50). The cultists purchased lots in Antelope, registered to vote, and took over the town government by overwhelming the small number of local residents. Now they had a more legitimate town government to work with and renamed the town Rajneesh.

Facing further local and state backlash, they turned to influencing the November 1984 Wasco County election. Their plan was to control the county by getting their members elected to a majority of the County commissioners as well as the sheriff. They attempted to get candidates on the ballot, but failed to get sufficient valid signatures.

Wasco County was too large to take over directly as with Antelope. Many of the commune's members were not US citizens. Oregon only required 20-days of residency before being allowed to vote. The commune attempted to boost their voter registration with a "Share-a-Home" program; they brought in thousands of houseless people to live in Rajneeshpuram and tried to get them to register them to vote. Many refused and left, citing an atmosphere of brain-washing and feeling they had been tricked. A month before the election County Clerk Sue Proffitt, citing evidence of fraud, halted new registrations. Oregon Secretary of State Norma Paulus required new voter registrations to have a hearing in the county seat. At the cut-off date for registration, the Rajneeshees halted their imports of houseless people.

At the first hearing just 14 voters of about 200 were registered. At the second hearing they didn't show up. They Rajneeshees decided to boycott the election. The effort had failed.

Instead, the Rajneeshpuram tested their backup plan: [make enough voters sick so they won't show up to vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_Rajneeshee_bioterror_attack). They cultured Salmonella and made "test runs" poisoning two county commissioners, spreading it throughout grocery stores, court houses, and salad bars sickening and hospitalizing hundreds of people. Fortunately there were no fatalities. This only boosted voter participation to keep the cultists out.

The Rajneesh leadership fled to Europe. They were extradited from West Germany and sentence to 20-years, but were released after 3 and moved to Switzerland. The mayor of Rajneeshpuram turned state's evidence. The Rajneesh himself outed their crimes claiming he was unaware at the time; he was arrested on immigration crimes and deported. He died in 1990 in India.

This was the first and largest bioterror attack in the US.

Going back to the question, it illustrates some of the powers county clerks and secretaries of state have to combat overt voter fraud via registration.

## References

- [Bhagwan’s Biggest Gamble: The Attempted Takeover of Wasco County](https://newrepublic.com/article/147915/bhagwans-biggest-gamble-attempted-takeover-wasco-county)
- [Bioterrorism and Biocrimes: The Illicit Use of Biological Agents Since 1900](https://fas.org/irp/threat/cbw/carus.pdf)
- [The Oregonian: Rajneesh](https://www.oregonlive.com/rajneesh/)

Answer (score 4):

There have absolutely been attempts to do that. See for example the Free State Project: https://www.fsp.org/

However, it appears that most people do not value political outcomes enough to upend their lives around them.

Comment: FSP is different, in that it was a commitment to *actually move* to a state, permanently, in order to influence its politics. OP was asking about temporarily registering to vote in a state to swing it in a presidential election.